# I'm not logged in automatically on SE blogs, unlike the rest of SE

Tags: feature-request, bug, login, blog-overflow

If I log in to one Stack Exchange site and then visit another site where I have an account, I'm automatically logged in to the second site as soon as I visit it. Even if the second site is one where I don't have an account, I can still access my global inbox and notifications dropdowns, and see the "join this community" link in the topbar instead of "log in".

So far so good ... but when I visit the SE **blog** associated to my site, I'm not logged in automatically. I have an account on [the SFF blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com) which is linked to my account on [the SFF main site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), but when logged in on the main site and following a link to the blog, I'm not automatically logged in on the blog until I visit [the admin page](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/wp-admin) (and I'm not even sure whether this link works for people who don't have an Administrator account on the blog).

Is this a bug? How hard would it be to **log people in automatically to a site blog when they're already logged in to the main site (assuming they have an account on the blog)**, in the same way as they'd be logged in automatically to any other SE site where they have an account?

Comment: Those blogs are WordPress, so the code behind is totally different. Adding login would be probably impossible.